# It appears that reports about plagiarized content cannot contain the word "duplicate"

Tags: discussion, status-norepro, flags, plagiarism

Just now I stumbled upon an answer that had a highly upvoted comment accusing it of plagiarism (from another answer on a different question), from many years ago. I checked out the claim and it was clearly plagiarism to me, so I decided to take my first stab at using the new system for flagging plagiarized comment.

As one might guess from the fact that an *applicable* answer (or at least code block) could be copied across, the other question was pretty closely related. However, I had already assessed (as part of my general curation work) that it was *not* a duplicate, and felt (for some reason) like it would be useful to say so in the flag message (I *was*, after all, asked to be specific.)

This resulted in an error message telling me not to use the plagiarized-content flag for duplicates, which doesn't make a lot of sense to me for *answers*. (The answers that I've been flagging as duplicates are generally considerably rephrased and likely to have been written from scratch, anyway.) I removed that text from my explanation and submitted the report successfully, so I am pretty confident that the system specifically objects to the word `duplicate`.

I can certainly see the use-case for such a filter so I do not want to call it a bug; but personally I'd like to think I don't need to be bothered in such a manner. Shouldn't it be enough to just put a textual warning *in the form itself*, on the "Plagiarized content" radio button?

Comment: Just type `dupl1cate` instead. [Pr0blam solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944).

Comment: If you seek for workaround you could use `Duplіcate` which is not the same as `Duplicate`.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda `і` see what you did there :D

Comment: From an accessibility standpoint, using U+0456: CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER BYELORUSSIAN-UKRAINIAN I instead of U+0069: LATIN SMALL LETTER I is probably not great. Think about screen readers, search engines, etc.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Well maybe stackoverflow will fix their bad filter faster then.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Ok about screen readers (although not sure if there is any diamond or staff members needing it?) but for search engine, remember this is the message in a flag, that is supposed to be only between moderators and the OP.

Comment: [More](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#problem) [variations](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#duplicate).

Comment: Amazing levels of patronizing here from SO. It's as bad as forbidding "error" and the like in question titles, except this is even worse because people raising flags are a far more filtered bunch than any rando seeing an "ask a question" button.

Comment: This doesn't seem to apply to moderators; does it prevent submission entirely, or just require clicking the submit button again like the migration warning?  It seems like if such a warning is to exist, it should be a _warning_, not an error, and be bypassable.

Comment: @RyanM I dismissed it too quickly to really check properly. It may well have only been a warning.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні to be fair, the filter is *only* 15 rep.

Comment: If only we had an A.I. that could do the filtering in an intelligent way, instead of filtering on single words..

Comment: @CarloWood if only there was an AI that could understand text like us, in natural language.. with all of it's intrincansies, and common sense included, that could do this for us...

Comment: @KarlKnechtel maybe 15 flags to raise a flag, but do you think there are many <500 rep users who 1. want to flag 2. do so helpfully enough? Because the "don't raise this kind of flag in this kind of situation" is a filter way higher than the "monkeys mashing keyboards" situation at 15 rep. So I don't believe the flag privilege rep limit is the relevant quality metric here.

Comment: Do you remember the text of the flag? A few people in chat have tried to reproduce this, without success.

Comment: [U+0131](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=300) ([LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotless_I)) has also been observed in the wild on Stack Overflow. There is also [U+0130](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%B0) (dotted I or i-dot), but this has never been observed (that does preclude its existence).

Comment: \**does not preclude*

Comment: @KarlKnechtel finally got a chance to take a look at this and I'm unable to repro this issue as any type of user, nor can I find code that might do this (and I implemented a lot of the plagiarism stuff myself and definitely did not put that in there!). Going to change the status for now but please let me know if you're able to repro at some point.

Comment: Just an observation here: I find it quite interesting to see +50/-2 on a bug report that AFAICT not a single person (including the OP) could reproduce, and that even the OP was not entirely sure about given they dismissed the alleged popup very quickly. Perhaps this bug report provides some deeper insight into site mechanics, or provides some other utility even if the bug report is incorrect, but I'm failing to see what that might be.